# C# / Visual Studio - Object is null unless I have a Breakpoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, google-contacts-api

I'm specifically using the Google Contacts API at the moment, but this could be true of other scinarios as well.

I have the following code:

```
Contact newContact = new Contact();
```

When I let the code run without any breakpoints, I get a NullReferenceException on all of the properties of this object.  However, if I put a breakpoint just after this line, I can see all of the properties have been initialises and the rest of my code executes fine.

Any idea's would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Single-step through the code and see what the `Contact` class's constructor does. As Raf suggests in his answer, it might do some kind of asynchronous I/O (it shouldn't, but when has that stopped anyone).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it takes a while to initialize `Contact` object (i.e. download data from internet). If it is done asynchronous then when you set a breakpoint you give program a time to do it.

Comment: I've tried putting Thread.Sleep(10000) immediately after the object initialisation.  I've also tried looping over Thread.Sleep(1) while the last of the objects properties is null to no effect.  Yet, as soon as I break into the code, the object is fully initialised.

Comment: hmm, maybe when you put breakpoint you also watch this object and somehow invoke one of the method that initializes it - of course I'm guessing. Hope somehow helping you